# IntelliJ update to new version failed

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-idea-2020

I have IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.2 on my laptop. When I did Help ->Check for Updates..., it said that "IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.4" is available. I would then select to proceed with the update. After it downloaded the patch files, it would then close the IDE. I would then briefly see an update pop-up windows, which would then disappear. After that, the IDE would launch again. But when I checked the version via Help -> About, I could see that I am still on 2020.1.2.

I tried a few times and it's always the same. I checked the idea_update.log, and I can see that the last few lines are "... Util$.visitFile...".

What could be the reason for the failure and what can I do?

On a desktop machine, I was able to successfully update to 2020.1.4, and then to 2020.2 (after a few tries due to connection failures and getting HTTP 503).

Comment: Is it possible to share update logs? As a workaround you may download installation file from official site and use it for update.

Comment: There is no error in idea_updater.log. The last few lines are just "... Util$.visitFile...". If I download installation file, would I run it like how I did it when I install IntelliJ the first time?

Comment: Sorry, but " few lines are just "... Util$.visitFile..."." is not informative. According to the second part - yes, just run it as for the first time and it will update your version keeping your settings.

Comment: I downloaded the installer and installed 2020.2. Now I have two versions on the same PC. This shouldn't be the case. During the installation, I checked the option to uninstall 2020.1.2, but apparently it did not do so.

Comment: You may uninstall them manually: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

Comment: Hi, I did uninstall the older version manually.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please check, that you can run

python --version

on the command line, and get something like

#Python 3.7.9

As I just found out, the updater depends on a working Python binary. If the command does not work, you most likely want to install Python